# Deciphering a bash command

Tags: linux, nlp, bash

I am looking for a program that can take a bash command as input, e.g.:

- `ls -lv`
- `ps aux | grep python | grep -v "grep python" | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9`
- `du -h --max-depth=1`
- `screen -dmS gp python search_convergence.py`

and explains what the command does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [explainshell](http://explainshell.com/):

- free
- online
- [open source](https://github.com/idank/explainshell)
- explain commands using the man pages:

[image]

Comment: neat! finally i can just reference a website instead of explaining all the parameters ...