# Convert all arguments in short-form to into their corresponding (if any) long-form arguments in a bash command

Tags: linux, bash

I am looking for a program that can convert all *short-form* arguments that are present a **bash** command to their corresponding *long-form* arguments.

For example:

```
wget -m -p -k http://stackexchange.com
```

should get converted to:

```
wget --mirror --page-requisites --convert-links http://stackexchange.com
```

If possible, free, Linux or Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate, doesn't change the parameters orders, and can take a long command as input (e.g. piped commands).

Comment: eh, that wouldn't be simple - you'd need to parse through the help file (and would that be /? or --help or....), match up the short and long commands, then replace them...

Comment: @JourneymanGeek yes a bit like http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/10386/903 I guess