# Deciphering a Windows CMD command line

Tags: windows

I am looking for a program that can take a bash command as input, e.g.:

- `shutdown /r /o`
- `Forfiles /p " C:\Backups\SQL " /d -6 /c "CMD /C del @FILE"`
- `dir c:\ /s /b | find "LOG" | more`

and explains what the command does, just like [explainshell does for bash commands](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/10386/903).

Comment: If anyone has any idea please add an answer.

Comment: I haven't found anything so far.